# Web3 returning Promise instead of value?

Tags: web3js, javascript, async

I have a simple async/await function get the total supply of my contract. It returns a promise, however.

```
async function supply() {
    const supply = await contract.methods.totalSupply().call()
    return supply
  }

  const s = supply()
  console.log(s)
```

The actual promise contains the correct value, and gets logged;

[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"

[[PromiseResult]]: "3"

How do I get the value?

Answer (score 1):

You need `await` your own async functions

```js
  const s = await supply()
```

Comment: I have to wrap that in its own async then. This would mean I could never call it outside of a function?

Comment: Correct. Everything must follow async path. If you want to easier to understand and simpler execution threaded model, please try Python and Web3.py: https://web3py.readthedocs.io/

Comment: I'm using React Hooks, where you cannot call async functions within the main component function. Is it just impossible to fetch the value then?

Comment: That is a different question. Please ask the question on stackoverflow.com or React forums how to use React, as it is not relevant for Web3.js discussion.